# Strategy for data management in React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux

## Context / Background

In a few projects now, I seem to face a common problem, and I still don't feel like I have created a solid way of tackling it.

I am using React, Redux, and React Router.

## Current state

In it's simplest, I have a page, with a series of saveable forms all of which can exist in both a view mode and an edit mode:

```
+--------------------------+
| EDIT MODE                |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|  <input name="A"/>       |
|  <input name="B"/>       |
|                          |
|  <button label="save"/>  |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|  <input name="C"/>       |
|  <input name="D"/>       |
|                          |
|  <button label="save"/>  | 
+--------------------------+

+--------------------------+
| VIEW MODE         [edit] |
+--------------------------+
|  readonly A              |
|  readonly B              |
|                          |
|  readonly A              |
|  readonly B              |
+--------------------------+
```

All the forms are wrapped up in a Request component, which takes a endpoint prop, and on mount will fetch the data. Once the request is complete it will render its children.

Sample page: url: `owner/1/pets`

```
const ownerId = props.params.id;

<Request endpoint={`api/owner/{ownerId}/pets`}>
    <OwnerDetails id={ownerId} />     
    <Pets ownerId={ownerId} />
  }}
</Request>
```

Reducer after request succeeds (noting already normalised):

```
{
    "tables": {
        "pets": {
            "1": { "id":"1", "name":"max", "owner": 1 },
            "2": { "id":"2", "name":"yella", "owner": 1 }
        },
        "owner": {
            "1": { "id":"1", "name": "jim" }
        }
    }
}
```

Then each Form is a connected component, and knows the slice of state it needs based on a simple passed in id.

Each Form also has an onChange action, that gets passed to each form input. onChange updates a "draft" slice of state.

So when the user types in the following input while in edit mode of pet 1:

The full state looks like:

```
{
    "tables": {
        "pets": {
            "1": { "id":"1", "name":"max", "owner": 1 },
            "2": { "id":"2", "name":"yella", "owner": 1 }
        },
        "owner": {
            "1": { "id":"1", "name": "jim" }
        }
    },
    "draft": {
        "pets": {
            "1": { "name": "new name" },
        }
    }
}
```

## Actions / Reducers

```
onChange => # updates the draft slice of state
save =>     # sends all data in draft to the server to be saved, upon being saved, the draft slice for that particular form is emptied, and table slice is updated with new data - in other words, the table slice is always the latest reflection of the server.
```

Connected forms will grab and merge table state with draft state to "get the full picture" when in edit mode. So if we're at the current reducer state above, and looking at pet 1, the connected form will grab all of tables.pets.1 data, then merge over the top draft.pets.1 data. In view mode, it only needs to grab the tables data (draft data is ignored in view mode).

## The problem

This feels somewhat overcooked. It feels awkward to extract and merge draft and table data, even when using selectors. The problems of updating and pulling data from store slices of state are exacerbated when forms can have nested elements.

## The question

What is a more concrete strategy of dealing with complex, multiple forms that can exist in a draft and state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a fairly solid approach overall.  It's actually pretty close to what I'm doing in my own app, although I don't have to "merge" data per se - all the data related to the item being edited gets copied to the "draft" slice when I start editing.

But yes, that approach looks good to me.

**edit**

Update: I've published a couple posts on Redux-ORM as the first two parts of [a series on "Practical Redux"](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-0-introduction/), discussing techniques I've developed from my own experience with Redux.  I plan to discuss the "draft editing" concept in a later post.

Second update: I've just posted [Practical Redux Part 8: Form Draft Data Management](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/), which shows how to implement the approach described here.

Comment: Thanks @markerikson (and thanks for your excellent contributions to the react community across your reddit input and mega list of awesomeness). I had debated copying across to draft upon clicking edit - it might simplify things a bit.

Comment: just wanted to also add to the above comment - it seems like maybe redux orm might be a good to simplify data structures on the front, esp when mapping to a backend

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably the foremost promoter of Redux-ORM (even more than its author @tommikaikkonen !).  I use it heavily in my app.  In fact, I'm hoping to write a series of blog posts describing stuff I've come up with in my app, and "use of Redux-ORM" and "managing draft data" are two of the topics I want to cover.  I listed my planned topics at https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/56lzxg/what_are_you_building_this_weekend/d8kg8xj/ a couple weeks ago.  Currently trying to work out some plausible scenarios as background for the posts.

Comment: Awesome! I will keep an eye for that! I'll check in on /r/reactjs for when the article/s get posted. Thanks

Comment: Heh.  I haven't actually submitted any of my posts on there yet, but I suppose I could.  I _have_ been tweeting a link out.  If you want to subscribe to the blog itself, it's at http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com .  I'd really like to make some progress on post prep this weekend, but we'll see how it goes.  Biggest issue is I want to give some good examples and use cases, not just throw up some bits of copy-pasta'd code and a few explanations.

Comment: Cool subbed to blog, easier than /r/reactjs anyway. I'll be refactoring some in-play work to redux-orm over the next week (currently working on it right now), so can provide some examples if you like.

Comment: And just one more comment: This discussion on redux-orm issues seems like /exactly/ what we've been discussing here https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm/issues/22 - so just a bit more input for future readers of this question

Comment: Yes, actually - that was _my_ issue :)  And yeah, that approach is what worked for me, and what you're describing in this question.

Comment: Ha, it is too! Nice! :)

Comment: I've added a small one file repo here https://github.com/cjke/redux-orm-draft-mode-example/blob/master/src/index.js  using your approach. Its using redux orm, plus the concept of copying all to draft

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a normalized structure.
1) You will cut down on the memory usage.
2) Updates would be quite easy.
[Redux Storage Strategy](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html)

For this I believe, https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr would be quite awesome.